# How to parse a file for words

Tags: python

For each word in a txt file, I want to set x as the first word in the file and y as the second. I tried this for loop but am unsure what I need to put in the < >.

My file has two lines with each word on a newline.

```
for word in file:
    x = <the first word>
    y = <the second word>
```

Comment: Is your file a bunch of lines with only two words? What's the structure etc? If it just has a single space you can unpack as `x, y = line.split()`. If your file just has lines with a single word on each line you can just do `words= file.readlines()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My file has two lines with each word on a newline.

If it only has two lines then you could do this (no loop required):

```
x, y = file.read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('path/to/file.txt') as file:
  x, y = [line.strip() for line in file]
```

Answer (score 0):

Read line by line and decide which is what with an extra variable. This method is good for very large files, because it does not needs to load the entire file into memory:

```
with open('workfile') as f:
    is_x = True
    for word in file:
        if is_x:
           x = word
        else:
           y = word

           do_things_on_x_and_y(x, y)

        is_x = not is_x
```